# Webview Interaction

Tags: swift

Is it possible to create a WebView Interaction in Swift? So i have a Login in HTML, and i want to insert some values in the (HTML Form) and press the Submit Button. With my Authentification i want to go to a specific URL (so with the same Session) and parse to HTML Content to display a native UITableView.

So parsing is not a big problem, also showing a Webview a get all the HTML Code. But, how can i make an interaction with an Webview?

And i dont need a visible WebView, is it possible to make all this requests without using a WebView?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To interact with `UIWebView`, you can use JavaScript by using the function

```
func stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(_ script: String) -> String?
```

The supplied string is a piece of JavaScript code which then will be executed in the `UIWebView` instance. The returning string contains the result.

For reference, have a look at [the documentation of `UIWebView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:).

Comment: Thanks. I have another question here. I have a MainViewController (for example a TabBar) and 5-6 Tabs. I want to show in every of this tabs another content from my "Website" - so i need in background a Session Cookie, and parse different URLs. Is this here possible without using a "visible" WebView?

Comment: Please open another question for this.